# Mono can't find Font or Color

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to use mono to compile C# but mono is returning the following errors:

```
CS0246: the type or namespace name 'Font' could not be found ...
CS0246: the type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found ...
CS0246: the type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found ...
```

My import statements look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Font;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
```

Any ideas? is the Font Class and Color Structure even supported in mono? I can't seem to find any documentation on what is officially supported and what is not if you could point me in the correct direction that would be great.

Comment: Have you included the reference to System.Drawing? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using VS 2013, but I am using mono from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when using mono from the command line, you do something like this:

```
$ mcs program.cs
```

You have to include, however, the assemblies referenced at the top of the file `program.cs`, such as **System.Drawing**. In order to do that, you have to use the `reference` switch:

```
$ mcs /reference:System.Drawing.dll program.cs
```

...until your program compiles.

Hope this helps.